# Insert values into database from data frame only into corresponding rows

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I have a variable dataframe which has variable values when the script is run on different occasions and the values are directly inserted to database.
For example, on first run, it may have:

```
column1   column2
A            2
B            1
C            3
D            5
```

while on other run, it may have:

```
column1   column2
A            4
B            6
D            8
```

what I am able to do for now inside the database:

```
column1    run1   run2 
A            2     4
B            1     6
C            3     8
D            5     -
```

What I want instead:

```
column1    run1   run2 
A            2     4
B            1     6
C            3     -
D            5     8
```

Please help me a find a way-around, if not the complete code.

Comment: post your code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `column1` as index and concat on `axis=1`:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('column1'),df2.set_index('column1')],axis=1,sort=False)
#for exact_match:-> pd.concat([df1.set_index('column1'),df2.set_index('column1')],axis=1,sort=False).fillna('-')

   column2  column2
A        2      4.0
B        1      6.0
C        3      NaN
D        5      8.0
```

Comment: That's great, but column2 values are inserting as text instead of int, Also the ```df2.to_sql('table_name', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False) 
``` is not writing the index(A,B,C,D,) to database, can you help?

Comment: @sudoCoder are you using `.fillna('-')` ? if yes, the columns are converted to object. May be that is the reason your sql has text.. Also Note that since your data has `NaN` it will convert to float.

Comment: Any idea about the index not being written?

Comment: @sudoCoder because we have set column1 as index and you pass index = False, it is not there, first do a `df_new=df_new.reset_index()` before writing it to sql

Answer (score 1):

I am writing in r you can convert it into python

```
   df1 = data.frame(col_1 = c('a','b','c','d'),col_2 = c(2,1,3,5))

   df2 = data.frame(col_1 = c('a','b','d'),col_2 = c(4,6,8))

   finaldf= merge(df1,df2, by = 'col_1' , all = TRUE)
```

you will get below output

```
    col_1 col_2.x col_2.y
     a       2       4
     b       1       6
     c       3      NA
     d       5       8
```

IF u dont want NA replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Use pd.merge

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how= 'left', on = 'col1')
```